# How can I do compile-time addition in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, type-level-computation

How can I do addition in the type system in TypeScript?

I can get successor (add 1) and predecessor (subtract 1) but haven't figured out how to get the recursion needed in order to add two numbers generally:

```
type Z = 0                           // zero
type S<T> = { item: T }              // successor
type P<T extends S<any>> = T['item'] // predecessor
type N = S<any> | Z                  // number, not exactly right because S<boolean> isn't a number

const zero = 0
const one: S<Z> = { item: 0 }
const two: S<S<Z>> = { item: { item: 0} }
const three: S<S<S<Z>>> = { item: { item: { item: 0 } } }

const predPred3: P<P<typeof three>> = one; // OK
```

The problem I'm hitting is with recursive type definitions:

```
// Error: Type alias 'Plus' circularly references itself
type Plus<T1, T2> = T2 extends Z ? T1 : Plus<T1, P<T2>>
```

I tried to hack around the problem by using `ReturnType` but the syntax isn't even correct:

```
function plus<T1 extends N, T2 extends N>(t1: T1, t2: T2) : T2 extends Z ? T1 : ReturnType<typeof plus<T1, P<T2>>> {
    return t2 === 0? t1 : plus({item: t1}, (t2 as S<any>).item);
}
```

Is there a way to do addition in the type system?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14833 .

Comment: Also found this, library using lookup tables for more efficient math in the type system: https://github.com/aman-tiwari/shape-types/blob/master/index.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To evade "Type alias 'Plus' circularly references itself" restriction, you have to reference recursive type in the object member type, then select appropriate member type using `[]` as [indexed type access operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types):

```
type Plus<T1, T2> = {
    z: T1;
    s: T2 extends S<any> ? S<Plus<T1, P<T2>>> : never 
       // conditional type necessary because compiler can't figure out
       // that T2 always extends S here, "never" branch is never taken
}[T2 extends Z ? 'z' : 's']


const p12: Plus<typeof one, typeof two> = three; // typechecks
```

However, be warned by [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897#issuecomment-401418254)

> > unless someone like @ahejlsberg can tell us if we can expect things
> >     like that to keep working or not
>
> It's clever, but it definitely pushes things well beyond their
>   intended use. While it may work for small examples, it will scale
>   horribly. Resolving those deeply recursive types consumes a lot of
>   time and resources and might in the future run afoul of the recursion
>   governors we have in the checker.
>
> Don't do it!

Answer (score 1):

You probably still shouldn't use this in production, but I've created the [`@rimbu/typical`](https://github.com/rimbu-org/rimbu/tree/main/packages/typical) library to do this. It basically performs calculations on template literal strings and converts them from and to numbers.

You can use it like this:

```
import { Num } from "@rimbu/typical"

type A1 = Num.Add<993, 12>
// type of A1 is inferred to be 1005

type A2 = Num.Subtract<1005, 12>
// type of A2 is inferred to be 993

type A3 = Num.Div<1005, 12>
// type of A3 is inferred to be 83
```

It has many more operations and also does similar tricks for type-level string manipulation.

You can see it in action in this [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rimbu-sandbox-d4tbk?previewwindow=console&view=split&editorsize=65&moduleview=1&module=/src/typical/num.ts&file=/src/typical/num.ts)